# Why is $L^2_0$ a complete subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded domain. How to reason that:
$$L^2_0(\Omega) = \{ q \in L^2(\Omega)\, |\, \int_{\Omega} q = 0\},$$
is a complete space?

Comment: Take advantage of the completeness of $L^2(\Omega)$. Show the limit of a Cauchy sequence of elements in $L^2_0(\Omega)$ has the property you want.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\int_\Omega q$ is the inner product $\langle q , \mathbf1_\Omega\rangle$, where $\mathbf1_\Omega \in L^2$, so the map $q \mapsto \int_\Omega q$ is continuous (by Hölder's inequality).